# SXA Navigation Component and Media Links

Tags: sxa

Does anyone know if the SXA navigation component can be made to render links that are not links to Sitecore XP pages but are media links instead? On the click of menu items a document should be downloaded.
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Your rendering variant needs to render a general link field referencing the media item.

Comment: Thank you Michael.

Comment: This post helped me
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8773/sxa-navigation-component-and-external-links